# Vue - Bug or design with template vslots

Tags: vue.js

I notice that some of my computed properties don't fire when they call upon the same data. As a super-simplistic example let's say I have this:

```
<template v-for="item in foo" v-slot:['sameSlot`]="{sameBlah}">
  {{ JSON.stringify(item) }} 
</template>
<template v-for="item in bar" v-slot:['sameSlot`]="{sameBlah}"> 
  {{ JSON.stringify(item) }} 
</template>
<template v-for="item in baz" v-slot:['sameSlot`]="{sameBlah}">
  {{ JSON.stringify(item) }}
</template>
...

data: () => ({
  someData: [
    {type:'foo', value: 1},
    {type:'bar', value: 2},
    {type:'baz', value: 3},
  ],
});
computed: {
  foo() {
    console.log('Hello from foo');
    return this.someData.filter(f => f.type === 'foo');
  },
  bar() {
    console.log('Hello from bar');
    return this.someData.filter(f => f.type === 'bar');
  },
  baz() {
    console.log('Hello from baz');
    return this.someData.filter(f => f.type === 'baz');
  },
}
```

If I run that, I only see console output from one of the computed methods, not all.  Same with seeing results in the templates.  Is this by design?

BTW I'm aware I could eliminate the computed properties by creating a method where a filter key could be passed in, but that doesn't showcase this 'issue'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the post targets the same slot 3 times, so Vue completely ignores the first 2 without running any of the code in the first two templates even once.

This is a smart feature to minimize workload because it's not sensible to target the same slot more than once to begin with.  If anything, maybe there should be a warning from the compiler in this situation.

You could even have code that tries to use variables which don't exist, and there will be no compiler warning.  For example:

```html
<!-- First call: completely ignored, no error -->
<template v-for="item in notDefinedOnTheInstance" v-slot:[`sameSlot`]="{sameBlah}">
  {{ JSON.stringify(item) }} 
</template>

<!-- Second call: used for the slot -->
<template v-for="item in baz" v-slot:[`sameSlot`]="{sameBlah}">
  {{ JSON.stringify(item) }}
</template>
```

Despite not existing in the instance, `notDefinedOnTheInstance` won't throw a warning because that whole section has been ignored.  So it's for this reason that you also don't see the computeds output in the console, because they never run.

Comment: This indicates in template compilation phase named slots are read from template and written under their `name` key. So second gets written over first and last over the second. Nice find.